# "System.Data.DataRowView” instead of actual values

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

In my DB, I have a table called CHIPSET which I use to retrieve data from the DB into the CheckedListBox on Form1. So far so good.
Now when I insert data into the DB, under the appropriate column, I get "System.Data.DataRowView" as many times as number of checked items selected. I have looked around here and I can't figure out how to fix this in my code.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DB db = new DB();
    SqlConnection connection;
    Chipset catg = new Chipset();
    Model model = new Model();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        loadComboCategory();
    }

    public void loadComboCategory()
    {
        checkedListBox1.DataSource = catg.getCategories();
        checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "CHIPSET";
        checkedListBox1.ValueMember = "CHIPSET_ID";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            string str = "";
            if (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (str == "")
                    {
                        str = checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[i].ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        str += ", " + checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[i].ToString();
                    }
                }
                connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=AOC_DB;Integrated Security=True");
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into data(Item_Id, Items) values(@Item_Id, @Items)", connection);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item_Id", textBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Items", str);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted Successfully");
                connection.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select atleast one item");
            }
            while (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices[0], false);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + e.ToString());
        }

        if (textBox1.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            db.openConnection();
            model.insertModel(textBox1.Text);
            MessageBox.Show("New AOC Model Inserted Successfully", "Insert AOC Model", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter The Model Name");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you get  in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[i].Value ?  I think you used the query result while binding data to listbox and now you are directly converting it to string. It will not work.

Comment: @ Gaurang Dave The value under checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[i] shows up correct "Intel X540" and when submitted to DB, comes up as "System.Data.DataRowView". I am very new to C#... Are there any examples in regards to how can I fix this?

Comment: Try str = checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[i].Value; to insert in DB. Remove str = checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[i].ToString();

Comment: The "checkedListBox1" would show correct item but passing data to the str would show "System.Data.DataRowView" . I was looking at adding "Value" as suggested, but that is not an option. The only thing to my disposal are "Equals", "GetHashCode", "GetType", "ToString".

Answer (score 0):

After messing around, I got it finally to work by replacing code

```
str = checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[i].ToString();
```

With this one

```
str = checkedListBox1.GetItemText(checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[i]);
```

And also replacing this

```
str += ", " + checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[i].ToString();
```

With this one:

```
str += ", " + checkedListBox1.GetItemText(checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[i]);
```

Comment: Other tips, unrelated to the problem: SqlConnection and SqlCommand are disposable, so put them in using blocks, or dispose them explicitly. Also, you could do: var str = string.Join(", ", checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Select(x=>checkedListBox1.GetItemText(x)));